# No such file or directory trying to codesign Qt app for Mac AppStore

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

I'm trying to codesign the app bundle produced by Qt using:

```
codesign -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyCompany Limited" --deep –-entitlements /Users/me/pathtomyentitlements/Entitlements.plist MyApp.app
```

But I always get the error:

```
–-entitlements: No such file or directory
```

The codesign works fine without the --entitlements flag. And yes my entitlements file does exist at that location. I have even tried copying to the directory where the codesign is being performed.

The entitlements file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: It might be the rendering on my phone but the first dash of your --entitlements looks different from the rest of the dashes. That might be it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Have been looked at that for ages! Should I add your comment as the answer?

Comment: Feel free to do so!

Answer (score 1):

The first dash of your `--entitlements:` looks different from the rest of the dashes. Compare

```
–-entitlements
--entitlements
```

The top is yours, the bottom is with two identical characters. Might be that you copied the text from  badly written webpage.

When in doubt, always manually write out commands to prevent this sort of copy-paste typos.

Answer (score 0):

As commenter rubenvb suggested there was an invalid character at the start of --entitlements probably from copying and pasting code from a web page describing how to do this.